# What is the best way to get a script to execute on the server and display the output of the script on the client using node.js?

Tags: node.js

I am developing a small web app where I want to be able to give my user the ability to press a button and be able to execute a script remotely on the server. I want the output of the script to be displayed on the client.

I am just trying to understand the best way there is to implement functionality like that. Are there any libraries/nodules that let you do something like that directly?

## Possible ways

1. Child.process()

Comment: Are you asking whether there are HTTP servers implemented in Node.js?

Comment: @FelixKling not quite. I want to be able to call say, a bash script on a server at the press of a button on the client. What I am looking for is something along the lines of RPC. So I call a bash script remotely and display the output of that on the client side.

Comment: Do you need to do this safely so scripts cannot mess with your server in evil ways?  Because, if so that requires a VM.  If not, you just need to know how to run the script (which depends upon what type of script it is) and then return the contents of stdio back to the user.

Comment: Depends on the script. using [child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) may help.
 example:
    exec('child process',function(err,stdout,stderr){})

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for sharing. And yeah, I am using some VM based application logic so it'll be safe.

Comment: @nava Yeah that seems to be a way. What are your views on exposing a server side function dealing with the script and exposing that to the client over RPC?

Comment: My work involves shell script and node.js. So i use exec or spawn(if you want the stdin to send inputs). As the shell script completes and output will be available in stdout. 

Important : Just search and user input before execution. which means sanitize the user input for JS scripts or any others command which will expose your server.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at node's `child_process` library. [Link](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process)

I've used the `.exec` function before, as that runs a script to completion and captures the output. That sounds like what your are looking for, just replace their example command with yours.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec,
    child;

child = exec('cat *.js bad_file | wc -l',
  function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

Wrap this call in a callback, and you'll get a response to the callback, and then to the client, when the script finishes. Be aware of the scripts your are running via a HTTP request. Open strings like "run any command" would be obvious security problems, and long running scripts would be a problem for HTTP timeouts. You could implement a WebSockets based solution and pipe results as they come (take a look at `.spawn` if you want to kick off a process and keep it running, and maybe interact with it later.)

Comment: I'll try this out. Yeah I am more in favor of a websockets implementation.